# "Does not contain definition for" error when using junction table created using .toTable() method in dbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The table "class1class2" is not being recognised.(See code below). I want to be able to use the junction table

**Context**

```
 public class context: DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
  modelBuilder.Entity<class1>()
  .HasMany(c => c.listofclass2).WithMany(i => i.listofclass1)
  .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("class1ID")
  .MapRightKey("class2ID")
  .ToTable("class1class2"));
  }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
context db = new context();
var r= db.class1class2;
```

class1class2 in the implementation code is not recognised

Comment: try `dynamic db = new context();` instead of `context db = new context();`

Comment: I got an error -> 'context' does not contain a definition for 'class1class2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is not recognized because it doesn't exist. When you map many-to-many relation this way there is no class used for the junction table. It is handled transparently through your navigation properties `listOfClass2` and `listOfClass1`.

If you want to have access to the junction table (which is useful only if the junction table contains additional data - not only foreign keys) you must create a class for that and map two one-to-many relations with this new class instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was following a tutorial that uses the junction table to perform crud operation on a many to many relationship. I makes sense now.